# Make [Field] a tag synonym of [Fields]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [field](/questions/tagged/field) and [fields](/questions/tagged/fields) both refer to form fields, [programming fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx), etc. I think they should be made synonyms.

Comment: +1 Part of the [long clean-up list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135994/172431)

Comment: @madth3 Wow, I didn't know about that (huge) list.  I'll check that first next time before I post any other synonym requests.

Comment: Well, as I understand it, that list is about _possible_ synonyms and it has not been officially targeted, so maybe specific requests like yours are still in order.

Comment: @animuson Someone's been busy I see! Keep up the good work!